# Spanish unicode characters SQLite

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with spanish provinces names, but I'm not able to decode unicode characters into NSString to be displayed correctly. For example :`Guip&uacute;zcoa`

With this:

```
self.provincia.text =[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:[[[provinciaArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"name"] UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I still see unicode characters.

Many thanks

Comment: Look like the issue is with the data entry, not the extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`&uacute;`" is not a "unicode character," and `NSString` has no reason to display it as anything but what it actually is.  After all, it is not `NSHTML`

You need to replace all occurences of that with the *actual* character.  You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to do the actual replacement.